# Vanity generator

Tags: address, vanity-address, address-generation, vanitygen

Imagine that there are two really strong computers that try to find an address starting with `1ABCDEFGH`. Is there a possibility does that two computer find the same private key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enough entropy in Bitcoin private keys to make this possibility extremely unlikely (just like with non-vanity address).

A nice chapter on vanity addresses (their generation, security etc) can be found at: http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001802/ch04.html#_vanity_addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Theres a possibility, its still unlikely.

heres a couple of attempts.  Not quite as many characters since it will take to long.

1AbcDeF22LQFTudvxEPzPUo4LQsNLVUUGT

1ABcDefEJv156aq32SmQo8aU4EVPHqwxV4

Case sensitive will take longer.

1ABCDEkreuP3HqnqEivk8NQzLw5afz3mXW

http://directory.io/ has a list of all bitcoin public/private keys

still looking for an atom in the galaxy.

Comment: Wait, I thought directory.io was fake? https://directory.io/faq Here it says its a joke.

Comment: @MCCCS it is a joke, but the data generated is real. It's just proving a point that being able to generate the data doesn't really help you, there are still so many addresses that it's impossible to search.